# How to bind "unnamed" properties to DataGrid with DataTemplates?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

What I have is a class which does not have "named" properties:

```
public class ColumnsValues
{
  public int IdProperty { get; set; }
  public string ColumnName { get; set; }
  public string ValueOfColumn { get; set; }
  public TypeCode TypeOfColumn { get; set; }
}
```

and data is stored in an "ObservableCollection coll" like that(for example, for **Person**):
[image]
Another example about **University**:
[image]

My goal is to create a `DataGrid` with `DataTemplates`. To accomplish my goal I use `DataTable` where I can define type of columns like that:

```
MyDataTable.Columns.Add("I am bool", typeof(bool));
```

and examples of `DataTemplates` for `DataGrid`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="IntTemplate">
   <StackPanel>
      <Label Content="I am int"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="BooleanTemplate">
   <StackPanel>
      <Label Content="Xo-xo Bool"/>
      <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=.}"/>
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Is there a better approach(not DataTable or improved this approach) to bind my class ColumnsValues to DataGrid without sacrifice of using DataTemplates for value types?

I know that there is a lot of chance that question to be closed, nevertheless I would like to try to ask about potential experiences. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you don't have properties defined at compile time, you may consider a class implementing the `ICustomTypeDescriptor` interface.

Comment: @MichaelSpranger could you show some example, please

Comment: @downvoter please, could you explain downvote?

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment, here is some crude sample code to illustrate the idea:

```
class DynamicPerson : ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    public ObservableCollection<ColumnsValues> Features { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ColumnsValues>();


    #region  ICustomTypeDescriptor  

    private CustomTypeDescriptor _customTypeDescriptor = new DynamicPersonTypeDescriptor();
    public String GetClassName() => _customTypeDescriptor.GetClassName();
    public AttributeCollection GetAttributes() => _customTypeDescriptor.GetAttributes();
    public String GetComponentName() => _customTypeDescriptor.GetComponentName();
    public TypeConverter GetConverter() => _customTypeDescriptor.GetConverter();
    public EventDescriptor GetDefaultEvent() => _customTypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent();
    public PropertyDescriptor GetDefaultProperty() => _customTypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty();
    public object GetEditor(Type editorBaseType) => _customTypeDescriptor.GetEditor(editorBaseType);
    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes) => _customTypeDescriptor.GetEvents(attributes);
    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents() => _customTypeDescriptor.GetEvents();
    public object GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd) => this;
    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes) => GetProperties();

    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        var collectionDescriptors = Features.Select(x => new DynamicPersonPropertyDescriptor(Features, x)).ToArray(); 
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(collectionDescriptors);          
    }

    #endregion


    class DynamicPersonTypeDescriptor : CustomTypeDescriptor
    { }

    class DynamicPersonPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
    {
        TypeConverter typeConverter;

        Collection<ColumnsValues> features;
        ColumnsValues feature;

        public DynamicPersonPropertyDescriptor(Collection<ColumnsValues> features, ColumnsValues feature)
            : base(feature.ColumnName, new Attribute[] { new BindableAttribute(true) })
        {
            this.features = features;
            this.feature = feature;
            typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(feature.Type);
        }

        public override Type ComponentType => feature.Type; 
        public override bool IsReadOnly => false;           
        public override Type PropertyType => feature.Type;  
        public override bool CanResetValue(object component) => true;
        public override object GetValue(object component) => typeConverter.ConvertFrom(feature.ValueOfColumn);

        public override void ResetValue(object component)
        {
            feature.ValueOfColumn = null;
        }

        public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
        {
            feature.ValueOfColumn = Convert.ToString(value);
        }

        public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component) => true;
    }

    public class ColumnsValues
    {
        public int IdProperty { get; set; }
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }
        public string ValueOfColumn { get; set; }
        public TypeCode TypeOfColumn { get; set; }
        public Type Type => Type.GetType("System." + TypeOfColumn);
    }
 }
```

Note that you could in principle derive `DynamicPerson` from the abstract class `CustomTypeDescriptor`, although that would probably be bad design.

This would be used like this

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var staff = new List<DynamicPerson>();
        var person1 = new DynamicPerson();
        var feature1 = new DynamicPerson.ColumnsValues
        {
            ColumnName = "FirstName",
            IdProperty = 1,
            TypeOfColumn = TypeCode.String,
            ValueOfColumn = "Albert"
        };
        person1.Features.Add(feature1);
        var feature2 = new DynamicPerson.ColumnsValues
        {
            ColumnName = "LastName",
            IdProperty = 1,
            TypeOfColumn = TypeCode.String,
            ValueOfColumn = "Dunno"
        };
        person1.Features.Add(feature2);
        var feature3 = new DynamicPerson.ColumnsValues
        {
            ColumnName = "Alive",
            IdProperty = 1,
            TypeOfColumn = TypeCode.Boolean,
            ValueOfColumn = "True"
        };
        person1.Features.Add(feature3);

        staff.Add(person1);
        staff.Add(person1);
        DataContext = staff;
    }
}
```

The XAML part:

```
    <DataGrid Name="Persons" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First name"  Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Alive" Binding="{Binding Alive}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

If you want to autogenerate the columns with `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`, DynamicPerson would also need to be adorned with the `[TypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(DynamicPersonDescriptionProvider))]` attribute. For this you would need to define an additional class `DynamicPersonDescriptionProvider` deriving from `TypeDescriptionProvider` and overriding the GetTypeDescriptor method.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! I upvoted. However, I could not create `DataGrid.Columns` in XAML as I do not know how many `Columns` I will have. Sometimes the quantity of columns can be 500. So I cannot declare `DataGrid.Columns` in XAML.

Comment: Have you tried the `TypeDescriptionProvider` attribute I suggested for that case? If that does not work, you can always generate the columns and the binding in code. But I suppose that is what you are trying to avoid in the first place.

Comment: Man, I cannot really catch your point about connection between 'TypeDescriptionProvider' and 'DataGrid.Columns'. Sorry for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: When the DataGrid wants to autogenerate its columns, it needs to know the properties of the type. In the usual case, this is done via reflection. Here the properties are defined dynamically. It initially does not have an instance of DynamicPerson at hand, so the ICustomTypeDescriptor interface methods can not be invoked. By specifying the `[TypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(DynamicPersonDescriptionProvider))]` attribute for the class, the DataGrid can instantiate a DynamicPersonDescriptionProvider that provides the information about the properties. Now the DataGrid can autogenerate the columns.